# Is Diego Carlo from History's Strongest Disciple Kenichi Mexican?

Tags: historys-strongest-disciple-kenichi

He is a master of Lucha Libre, uses some occasional Spanish words (Rachel Stanley even calls him "maestro"), and his name sounds vaguely Hispanic. I don't know if it has been stated explicitly on the Manga or somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know anything about the show, but "maestro" is Italian, not Spanish.

Comment: @kuwaly It's also Spanish http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/maestro

Comment: I think so, he use some words in spanish and Lucha libre is a mexican fight and his name is a spanish (mexican) kind. But i dont remender of any dialog in manga about it.